# Page numbers in Beamer handouts

Tags: beamer, page-numbering, handout

I am making some handouts with Beamer, but I don't manage to get page numbers in the document. I print 4 frames on each page, and I do get the frame numbers, but I need the page numbers as well. It seems I can't add these directly in the resulting pdf, at least not with my Adobe Acrobat Reader DC, so it seems it must be done beforehand, before converting the document into pdf. Here is an example of what I put in the preamble.

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm, landscape]
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\scriptsize{\vspace*{0.3cm}\hspace*{0.3cm}

\insertframenumber}}
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\insertshorttitle\expandafter{%
      \insertshorttitle\hfill%
      \insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}

\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

\usetheme{Szeged}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{tipa}
    \usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{cgloss4e}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xyling}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{phonetic}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}

% \strikeout{text}: prints a struck-out version of #1
\newlength{\howlong}
\newcommand{\strikeout}[1]{
 \settowidth{\howlong}{#1}%
 #1\unitlength0.5ex%
 \begin{picture}(0,0)
 \put(0,1){\line(-1,0){\howlong\divide\unitlength}}
 \end{picture}%
}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
\leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{palette quaternary}%
    \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{\hskip0pt plus1filll}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  }
}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line foot}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
        leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{author in head/foot}%
        \leavevmode{\usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor}%
        \hfill%
        \leavevmode{\usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle}%
        \hfill%
        {\usebeamerfont{institute in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{institute in head/foot}\insertshortinstitute}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line foot}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\setbeamercovered{transparent=30}
\beamertemplateballitem


\title{XXX}
\subtitle{YYY}
\author{ME}
\institute{Mordor}
\date{\today}

\newcommand{\textunderscript}[1]{$_{\text{#1}}$}

\begin{document}

\frame {
\frametitle{Flaflafla}

xxxxxxxx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Offtopic, but with `beamer` you do not need packages like `graphics` or `color`,  they are already provided by `beamer`.

Answer (score 1):

The following will add a pagenumber at the bottom

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm, landscape]
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\scriptsize{\vspace*{0.3cm}\hspace*{0.3cm}\insertframenumber}}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\insertshorttitle\expandafter{%
  \insertshorttitle\hfill%
  \insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}

\makeatletter
\def\pgfsys@endpicture{%
    \makebox[\pgfphysicalwidth]{\the\numexpr\value{page}/4\relax}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\frame{}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

***Edit:***

with the MWE from the question

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm, landscape]
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\scriptsize{\vspace*{0.3cm}\hspace*{0.3cm}

\insertframenumber}}
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\insertshorttitle\expandafter{%
      \insertshorttitle\hfill%
      \insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}

\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

\usetheme{Szeged}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{tipa}
    \usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{cgloss4e}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xyling}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{phonetic}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}

% \strikeout{text}: prints a struck-out version of #1
\newlength{\howlong}
\newcommand{\strikeout}[1]{
 \settowidth{\howlong}{#1}%
 #1\unitlength0.5ex%
 \begin{picture}(0,0)
 \put(0,1){\line(-1,0){\howlong\divide\unitlength}}
 \end{picture}%
}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
\leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{palette quaternary}%
    \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{\hskip0pt plus1filll}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  }
}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line foot}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
        leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{author in head/foot}%
        \leavevmode{\usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor}%
        \hfill%
        \leavevmode{\usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle}%
        \hfill%
        {\usebeamerfont{institute in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{institute in head/foot}\insertshortinstitute}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line foot}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\setbeamercovered{transparent=30}
\beamertemplateballitem


\makeatletter
\def\pgfsys@endpicture{%
    \makebox[\pgfphysicalwidth]{\the\numexpr\value{page}/4\relax}%
}
\makeatother

\title{XXX}
\subtitle{YYY}
\author{ME}
\institute{Mordor}
\date{\today}

\newcommand{\textunderscript}[1]{$_{\text{#1}}$}

\begin{document}

\frame {
\frametitle{Flaflafla}

xxxxxxxx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, unfortunately that does not seem to work. Still no page numbers...

Comment: @EspenJK Strange! I get a number at the bottom of the page, see the screenshot.

Comment: Yes, it is indeed strange. For me, it does not give page numbers, and it also seems to mess up all frames carrying bullet points or similar... It could be related to something else in the preamble, then. I will provide the complete preamble.

Comment: @EspenJK Therefore, I think that creating a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) would be useful. Indeed, by reducing your code, you might identify what part causes the page number not to be printed.

Comment: Right, I've tried that... Removing parts of the preamble results in different types of small errors, but I still haven't found anything that adds the page numbers. Not even the minimal example suggested above by Sam Carter.

Comment: @EspenJK I tried with the MWE from your question, and it still works. A few questions to debug: How are you compiling? pdflatex? Which distribution are you using? I am on Texlive 2016.

Comment: @samcarter thanks, I use Winedt 9.1 and after running LaTeX I convert to pdf by using ps2pdf...

Comment: @EspenJK can you try with `pdflatex` instead of `latex` to see if this makes the number disappear?

Comment: @Ok, so I tried that, but it didn't help, either... It's a strange thing. And these damn PDF-readers don't allow you to even add page numbers without monthly subscriptions...

Comment: @EspenJK Which Tex Distribution are you using? Please don't say `Windedit`, that's an editor. MikTeX or TeXLive? Which Version?

Comment: Right, sorry. I am using MixTeX 2.9.

Comment: @EspenJK Sounds fairly recent. Than I am officially out of ideas, what might be the problem, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to `pgfpages` could be `pdfpages`. In this case, you create the beamer presentation, an later on include it as an external file inside the `handout` document which could be something like:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, landscape]{article}
\usepackage[vmargin={2cm,1.5cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=1-8,nup=2x2,frame, scale=.9, delta= 10 10, pagecommand={}]{Numeracio}
\end{document}
```

[image]